# Bootstrap 4 align brand and links

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <style type="text/css">

  </style>
  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light bg-faded container" style="background-color: #FFFFFF">
    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/84x100" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt="">
      <h1>Navbar</h1>
    </a>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
      <div class="navbar-nav">
        <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <h2>Heading</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi. Nulla quis sem at nibh elementum imperdiet. Duis sagittis ipsum. Praesent mauris. Fusce nec tellus sed augue semper
          porta. Mauris massa. Vestibulum lacinia arcu eget nulla. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Curabitur sodales ligula in libero. </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- jQuery first, then Tether, then Bootstrap JS. -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I'm working with bootstrap 4 and trying to setup the brand as a tall image and text underneath. I would like to have the image sit ontop of the text and both be entered. Is there a built in way to do this using bootstrap or does it require custom css? Most of this is pulled from the bootstrap website, but what I have does not have the logo centered. The links on the navbar and the brand are also not aligned at the bottom.

Comment: align-self-center and d-flex ? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aymWOV

Comment: Adding align-self-end to #navbarNavAltMarkup does work but switches the toggle nav bar from left to right. Any way to align brand and nav links but keep the togle navbar on the left?

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap has a class 'text-center' that should work as you need it. In your example apply it to the element with the class 'navbar-brand'.